# Removing a certain number out of a session array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I have a button next to all my 'shop items' that can remove one of the shop item, however i need it to just remove one, and not rid the entire array of the number, i thought this was possible by using a break statement when i found the number i want to remove, but it removes all of the numbers.

```
            if (isset($_GET['remove']) && isset($_SESSION['shopitems'])) {
            if (in_array($_GET['remove'], $_SESSION['shopitems'])) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['shopitems']); $i++) {
                    if ($_SESSION['shopitems'][$i] == $_GET['remove']) {
                        $shopArray = $_SESSION['shopitems'];
                        if(sizeof($shopArray) == 1) {
                            $_SESSION['shopitems'] = null;
                            $_SESSION['added'] = null;
                        } else {
                            array_splice($shopArray, $i, $i);
                            $_SESSION['shopitems'] = $shopArray;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here i check if the URL contains the remove variable and the session is set, once i have done this, i check if the array contains the number that is put in the URL, if so i'll start a for loop and check if the key index of the session shop items is equal to the URL variable, if so i want to remove it, however if i use array_splice, suddenly they are all gone, is this because of the function i am using? Or is the break not executing correctly?

Comment: `$_SESSION['shopitems'] = null` will clear all shopitems array. You need to clear the desired item only something like this `$_SESSION['shopitems'][$i] = null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)? It's easier, have a look at the code below and adapt it to your situation:

```
$array = [1, 5, 6, 12];
$wantToRemove = 5;

$key = array_search($wantToRemove, $array);
unset($array[$key]);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i didn't think about using the array_search function, i recently started using PHP so it's still kind of new to me!

Answer (score 0):

You can format your `$_SESSION['shopitems']` like this :

```
$_SESSION['shopitems'] = array (
  "item_id" => "item_info",
  "item2_id" => "item2_info",
  ...
)
```

and do `unset($_SESSION['shopitems'][$_GET['remove']])`.

Your code could be :

```
if (isset($_GET['remove']) && isset($_SESSION['shopitems']))
   if (isset($_SESSION['shopitems'][$_GET['remove']]))
      unset($_SESSION['shopitems'][$_GET['remove']])
```